# Error with function definition in fortran

Tags: function, fortran, gfortran

I am writing the following code in fortran and having error with the function definintion

```
program bisection_method
implicit none
real:: a=2.5,b=4.5,c,f

if (f(a)*f(b).gt.0) then
  write(*,*) "error"
else
  do while ((b-a)/2.0>0.0001)
  c = (a+b)/2.0
    if (f(a)*f(c).lt.0) then
      c = a
    else
      c = b
    endif
  enddo
endif

write(*,*)"the root is ",c
end program

function f(x)
 implicit none
 real::f,x
 f=(16*(x^3)-385*(x^2)+6000*(x)-3125)
end function f
```

and having the following error

```
fbisection.f90:24:9:

  f=(16*(x^3)-385*(x^2)+6000*(x)-3125)
         1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)
```

Any idea why this is happening? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `^` with `**`, which is the exponentiation operator (the `^` character is not an operator in fortran).

Just replace said line with:

```
f=(16*(x**3)-385*(x**2)+6000*(x)-3125)
```

Comment: Didn't know that, thank you!